# How to create zip from base64 zip content received from http response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, jszip

what I want to achieve is I have an API which is returning a zipped content as base64 content, I want to consume that API in JavaScript and using that content again want to create zip file and download that to clients system

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the base64 content from the API you can download that as zip file like below.

```
var byteCharacters = atob(base64);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var blob = new Blob([byteArray],{type:'application/zip'});
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = blobUrl;
link.setAttribute('download', 'reports.zip');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```